# User constantly registering and unregistering

Tags: discussion, policy

The question ["Are “here” and “now” diffeomorphism invariant concepts?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35851/are-here-and-now-diffeomorphism-invariant-concepts) is being bumped from time to time by new users.

I suspect users [Multiverse Philosopher](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12013/multiverse-philosopher), [Nonsensical ranter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12228/nonsensical-ranter), [Naughty problem child](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12295/naughty-problem-child), [Childish boy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12077/childish-boy) being the same person registering, leaving answers to his own question and unregistering.

Is there a policy on such a behavior?

Comment: None of the links in the question work.

Comment: @Physikslover they were deleted, I don't mind since as for me the question was offtopic as well as the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the answers are all useful, it's not really a problem. There's nothing wrong with a single user having multiple accounts as long as they don't use those accounts to vote for each other.

Of course, if you think you see something like this happening, flag it for moderator attention and we'll take a look at it.